# apt search "package-name" /w color

Tags: apt, search, grep

So I run something like :

```
sudo apt search "package-name" | grep --color -E 'installed|$'
```

which will highlight the string "installed" but I would like to chain two commands so that it would also highlight string "-dev" (or whatever).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Looks like a job for supercat - http://supercat.nosredna.net/

Comment: Doesn't `installed|$` just match everything anyway? If you just want to match installed packages, you may find `apt list --installed` useful

Comment: That is useful. I don't know. Maybe there is a better way to achieve my task. Still learning. What I'm wanting to do is cross check what packages I have installed against dependencies I need to build another package from source. Don't know the best way to do this

Comment: Not really an answer as your question is how to colorize output. supercat will do what you want, see the link I gave you. Use auto-apt to resolve dependencies see https://www.howtogeek.com/106526/how-to-resolve-dependencies-while-compiling-software-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 3):

You can add another string to match to the current pattern:

```sh
... | grep --color -E 'installed|-dev|$'
```

Comment: Nice one! Exactly what I was after. Obliged.